# why won't this combo animate: sleep-for n and next-line

Tags: elfeed

Why can't I see this "animation"?
I only see the end result.
This function is invoked via a keyboard shortcut
on a elfeed-search buffer.

```
(defun my/elfeed-extra-info-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (next-line)
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
  (sleep-for 0.5)
  (next-line)
)
```

Comment: reading http://dantorop.info/project/emacs-animation/lisp2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try swapping `sleep-for` with `sit-for`

Like they do it at  dantorop.info/project/emacs-animation/lisp2.html